# inline form two rows in bootstrap 3 jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm trying to have an inline form that takes two rows in the bootstrap jumbotron.

For each "row" of form elements, I assign each group of inputs a col-md-* so that the form elements are nicely aligned and take an equal amount of space.

What I am noticing however is that there is too much space between my form elements and the form elements do not fill up to take the full space of the columns assigned to them. Do I need to specify the width of each element? or do I need a fixed width container around the form?

Here is a bootply link http://www.bootply.com/aIhtGnedeN

How can I have a compact two rowed inline form in the jumbotron while retaining responsiveness? Should I put a fixed div arounded the form?

Comment: Please create a bootply(http://www.bootply.com/new) of your current problem with sample data.

Comment: you want to set the input width to 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the bootstrap docs for inline-forms:

> **Requires custom widths**
>   Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap. To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form controls used within.

you have to set the widths manually. Use this `CSS` for example:

```
.jumbotron .form-inline input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lCeW4ug7f4)